# DO i need to put mapping in hibernate config

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

On internet tutorial says that i have to add

```
<mapping class="com.vaannila.student.Student" />
<mapping class="com.vaannila.student.Phone" />
```

in the hibernate config file

But i am using annotations and in one example which i tested i didn't used mapping anywhere in file and it was working . so i am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using annotations, you **do not** need a Hibernate XML config file. The point of the annotations is to eliminate such a need.

The XML-file method of configuring ORMs came first, and is generally regarded as a more verbose, cumbersome, and (generally speaking, mind you) worse method. This is in comparison to the newer annotations-based configuration which you've already experimented with.

#### Recommended reading

- [hibernate using annotations or using hibernate configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624174/hibernate-using-annotations-or-using-hibernate-configuration-files)
- [Mixing JPA annotations and XML configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838898/mixing-jpa-annotations-and-xml-configuration)

Comment: I found the annotations way the most intuitive to use and less manual work compared to hbm files

Comment: But then why did that this example http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html used both

Comment: @Name: I have no idea why. You do not need both. I strongly suggest finding a better learning resource, such as [The Hibernate Tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) (online) or O'Reilly's [Harnessing Hibernate](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517724/index.html) (dead tree edition).